# Creation of a weighted raster overlay map using Ischrone (travel time) buffers, is it possible?

Tags: qgis, raster, weighted-overlay

I am a beginner utilising GIS and QGIS specifically and I am currently using the software to study housing suitability in a defined study area using a sustainable development framework for my final MSc project.

I intend to use QGIS to conduct Multi criteria decision analysis to identify suitable housing sites within the defined area using the following criteria.

1. Proximity to supermarkets
2. Proximity to green spaces
3. Proximity to Public transport links
4. Proximity to central business districts
5. Specific distance away from flood risk areas.
6. Proximity to education centres
7. Proximity to exercise facilities
8. Proximity to road network
9. Land use type

Researching tutorials available online I have found examples of users who have conducted Raster weighted overlay analysis using criteria such as my own, however these users appear to use distance to nearest variables (IE closest supermarket) to create their suitability map whereas I would preferably like to use Buffers to find how many supermarkets are within 1km radius for example.

Secondly most of the users used Euclidean straight line distance measurements to create their suitability maps whereas I would prefer to find a method that shows isochrone travel time buffers to supermarkets and greenspaces etc. I have used a plugin called Traveltime to created isochrone travel buffers for test points, however given these are buffers around specific shpfile points I wonder if this is not applicable for overlay analysis.

My overarching question I suppose from this discussion is whether what I desire is feasible to produce on QGIS or other GIS software. This may not feasible and it would be a big help for me to know so I don’t chase the impossible.

My secondary idea was to use the Euclidean/closest to nearest variable overlay analysis to act as an initial site selection/exclusion tool by ruling out large swathes of my study area using MCDA and then select 15-20 viable sites from these results. Sites would then be marked on the map and subjected to isochrone buffer analysis using my criteria and scored accordingly. This would then be used to rank the 15-20 viable sites based upon combined criteria suitability.

Comment: This is absolutely possible, albeit in the vector data domain; by utilizing graph theoretical frameworks (network routing) like *pgRouting* for PostgreSQL/PostGIS, or high performant standalone routing engines like OSRM/Valhalla. There should also be some plugins for QGIS, too, which may be sufficient if the study area is not too large.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the feedback i will give the recommendations you have provided a shot. Hopefully i can use them to help map the area based upon amount of criteria (IE: Supermarkets) within a 1km travel buffer.